# Socket gets disconnected with transport error in android but works smoothly in the iOS app

Tags: android, socket.io

I used the following set of code to integrate socket in my app, the socket disconnects just after connection and gives transport error as the only log visible. However, for the same URL, iOS app is working smoothly.
The code I used in the iOS app is as follows:

```
[.reconnects(true), .reconnectAttempts(5), .reconnectWait(3), .log(false), .forcePolling(false), .forceWebsockets(false),.forceNew(false),.secure(false),.selfSigned(false ,.path("/socket.io-client/")]


public void socketConnection() {

        try {

            HostnameVerifier myHostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            SSLContext mySSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {


                    return new X509Certificate[]{};
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                               String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    System.out.println("===socket==checkClientTrusted=authType==" + authType);


                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                               String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    System.out.println("===socket==checkServerTrusted=authType==" + authType);


                }
            }};


            mySSLContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());


            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .hostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier)

                    .sslSocketFactory(mySSLContext.getSocketFactory(), new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                            try {
                                System.out.println("checkClientTrusted " + authType);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                            try {
                                System.out.println("checkClientTrusted " + authType);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new X509Certificate[0];
                        }
                    })
                    .build();


            IO.setDefaultOkHttpCallFactory(okHttpClient);
            IO.setDefaultOkHttpWebSocketFactory(okHttpClient);
            IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
            opts.path = "/socket.io-client";
            opts.secure = false;
            opts.transports = new String[]{Polling.NAME};

            opts.forceNew = true;
            opts.callFactory = okHttpClient;
            opts.webSocketFactory = okHttpClient;

            mSocket = IO.socket(Urls.socket_url, opts);


            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECTING, onEvenConnecting);
            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onError);
            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onEvenConnect);
            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
            mSocket.connect();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where is your Android code?

Comment: @RuchiraRandana I used the method **socketConnection()** in the above snippet for the connection.

Comment: Did you found solution to it? If yes, please answer your question as it will help the community.